# Set focus of an entry from ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I've read about messaging, triggers, behaviors, etc. ... all seems a bit overkill for what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a repeating data entry screen in xaml that has 1 picker, 2 entries, and 1 button.  The picker, once a value is selected, keeps that selection.  The 1st entry does the same as the picker.  The 2nd entry is the one that is always getting new values.

I want to collect the filled in values on click of the button and then clear the last entry field of its data and put focus back on that entry so the user can enter a new value and hit save.  repeat repeat repeat etc.

I understand the MVVM model and theory - but I just want to put the focus on an entry field in the xaml view and am completely stumped.

EDIT to add code samples

view.xaml:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="5" 
             Padding="10,10,10,0">
    <Picker x:Name="Direction" 
             Title="Select Direction" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Directions}"
             ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDirection}"/>
    <Label Text="Order"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Order}" 
           x:Name="Order" />
    <Label Text="Rack"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Rack}" 
           x:Name="Rack" />
    <Button Text="Save" 
            Style="{StaticResource Button_Primary}" 
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            CommandParameter="x:Reference Rack" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Summary}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

viewmodel.cs

```
    public ICommand SaveCommand => new DelegateCommand<View>(PerformSave);

    private async void PerformSave(View view)
    {
        var scan = new Scan()
        {
            ScanType = "Rack",
            Direction = SelectedDirection.Name,
            AreaId = 0,
            InsertDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            ReasonId = 0,
            ScanItem = Rack,
            OrderNumber = Order,
            ScanQty = SelectedDirection.Value,
            IsUploaded = false
        };

        var retVal = _scanService.Insert(scan);

        if (!retVal)
        {
            await _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Error", "Something went wrong.", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            view?.Focus();
            Rack = string.Empty;
            Summary = "last scan was great";
        }
    }
```

Error shows up in this section:

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(RackPage));
        Direction = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Picker>(this, "Direction");
        Order = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Entry>(this, "Order");
        Rack = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Entry>(this, "Rack");
    }
```

Comment: Getting an error in the initialize section of page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the Entry as a `View` parameter to your view model's command. Like that:

```
public YourViewModel() 
{
    ButtonCommand = new Command<View>((view) => 
    {
        // ... Your button clicked stuff ...
        view?.Focus();
    });
}
```

And from XAML you call this way:

```
<Entry x:Name="SecondEntry" 
       ... Entry properties ...
       />
<Button Text="Click Me"
        Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Reference SecondEntry}"/>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can't seem to get this working ... I am getting an invalid cast error when trying to get the Entry object

Comment: @BTI-Doug Do you mean like `var obj = (view as Entry);`? You don't need it specifically as an entry. All `View` has the `Focus` method. Why are you trying to cast?

Comment: @BTI-Doug you forgot the bracket on `CommandParameter="x:Reference Rack"`, it should be `CommandParameter="{x:Reference Rack}"`...And I suggest you change the `Entry`'s name to `txtRack`, for example. It's confusing with the VM's property name

Comment: BOOM!  Stupid me - that was it!  Thank You!

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I am having similar situation and your answer is very helpful.  I'd just comment, wouldn't it be better to pass to the Command the entire code-behind view rather than just the Entry view?  That way, in code behind, you can create a method to do focusing on a view and you call that method from the command instead of calling Focus on the single view?

Comment: @cd491415 It can bring you an immediate facility, but it implies your view model should know your entire view, what is not a good choice.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Good point!  But would not same apply for VM knowing about Entry from the view?  Thanks again

Comment: @cd491415 Sure, it does! I bet the best choice is to write a custom control, based on `Entry` with an property command that handles the focus after the default command calling, for example. Maybe another approach like this. But I'm sure it's not the better implementation but for now it does the trick . Nice coding

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza by default command you mean?  ... and thank :)

Comment: @cd491415 Yes. Of course, it can bring the spotlight to some other problems, for instance, _what if the command result (a business rule) thrown a message alert, or depending on its field value, the focus should be to a different field_... particularly I prefer to avoid this type of implementation that trenches the user, I think it's very intrusive and non-natural.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CommandParameter in the XAML and use that in the viewmodel.

In Xaml:

```
<ContentView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<Image Source="downarrow" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
<ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SecurityPopupCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference AnswerEntry}"/>
</ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
</ContentView>
```

In view model:

```
public ICommand SecurityPopupCommand { get { return new Command(OpenSecurityQuestionPopup); } }
private void OpenSecurityQuestionPopup(object obj)
{
     var view = obj as Xamarin.Forms.Entry;
     view?.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can set the focus of an entry from the XAML, but from the page, you could just use the function `Focus` of the `Entry` on the Clicked Event:

```
saveButton.Clicked += async (s, args) =>
{
    //save the data you need here
    //clear the entries/picker
    yourEntry.Focus();
};
```

Comment: I don't want the entry to always get focus - only after the save button is clicked.

Comment: Could something like the updated answer work out? @BTI-Doug